# Combining Java & xml spring configuration for testing

Tags: java, spring, testing

It is explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-java-combining) how combining java & xml configuration is done. It works. Test Context framework has java config support since 3.1.0.M2 :

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class LangDetectorTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
@Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public LangDetector langDetector() throws SystemException {
            LangDetector orderService = new LangDetector();
            return orderService;
        }
    }
}
```

Though I can't figure out how to have java config as the main configuration and load something like util:properties and stuff from XML configuration.

I'd need to do somwthing like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ImportResource("classpath:context/LangDetectorTest-test.xml")
public class LangDetectorTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Configuration
        static class ContextConfiguration {

            @Bean
            public LangDetector langDetector() throws SystemException {
                LangDetector orderService = new LangDetector();
                return orderService;
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise java config support for Test Context framework is useless, considering that there are tons of things that can be done only via XML configuration.

Comment: Bear in mind that Spring 3.1 isn't finished yet.  The Milestone builds are feature-incomplete, so don't be surprised if things seems to be missing.

Comment: @skaffman: So that now it is not implemented but it will most probably in 3.1 RC+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [springsource blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/) :

> For Spring 3.1 RC1 we plan to introduce a
>   DelegatingSmartContextLoader that will delegate to a list of candidate
>   SmartContextLoaders (i.e., GenericXmlContextLoader and
>   AnnotationConfigContextLoader) to determine which context loader is
>   appropriate for a given test class's configuration. The winning
>   candidate will then be used to actually load the context. Once this
>   work is complete, DelegatingSmartContextLoader will replace
>   GenericXmlContextLoader as the default loader. Feel free to follow the
>   progress of this development in JIRA: SPR-8387.